# Probability of duplicate OTPs generated in a window using OAUTH HOTP?

Tags: authentication

I am using HOTP to generate OTP for second factor authentication. I am using event-based generation of OTP and providing a window of 10 iterations should there be mismatch in the counter of client and server.

However, I am being asked that what happens if an OTP is re-generated from past at any point of time.

Since the OTP is a 6 digit number, there could be only 999999 combinations available for a user. Hence, an OTP cannot be unique in the lifetime and it will be regenerated at some point. Could there be a pattern when a particular OTP repeats?

Also, if an OTP is regenerated within a window size of 10, it could be worse as it would be vulnerable to replay attack.

Kindly guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there should not be a repeating predictable pattern if you don't know the secret key by using [randomness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password#How_OTPs_are_generated_and_distributed) (it would be an important discovery and flaw in the algorithm to be otherwise).

Although you can tolerate a windows size of 10, only tolerate that going forward. Never accept a token that is less than the last confirmed counter, otherwise you are leaving open a replay attack.

HOTP, TOTP or anything else isn't immune to all forms of attack, of course, so you need a multi-layered approach to your security that is realistic about the vectors of attack vs. the cost of defending.

A more in depth discussion is probably best had [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/). In this answer I'm trying to stick the implementation issues.